# SharePoint Online List performance slow on new item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

SharePoint Online List performance issue, when i click on new item or new form i face delay in opening new form. I was wondering how improve the performance of the list library. I have more than 1k items in this list.

Comment: Are you using the classic or modern list experience?

Comment: Modern list experience

Comment: Does the new form appear as a dialog from the right or does it open a new page?

Comment: Dialog appears from right

Answer (score 0):

For list performance, common steps are like below, have a try:

1. Add indexes on columns.
2. Edit the view and apply filters. Make sure only a portion of items will get diplayed under the current view.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

And commonly 1k items shall not have sever performance issue which will cause delay on opening new form. Are you using a heavily customized list form? Or you have a huge number of columns?

Comment: I had checked i have 20+ columns but items are more than 5k i guess. And not customized form we are using default form.

Comment: @striker92, that sounds much more reasonable. As you are exceeding the list view threshold, just try the suggestions and check the performance again. And too many item-level unique permission will also cause a performance issue. Have a check